# Ruby on Rails: Minify or Compress Javascript Files?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, compression

Currently there is this in my `<head>`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.3.min', 'jquery.form', 'jquery.validate', 'script', :concat => true %>
```

This means Rails produces an `all.js` File with all js-files combined in it.

Is there some way in Rails to also minify or compress the js files? I mean like getting rid of comments, whitespace, whatever a js compressor typically does. I'm just curious because with an automated compression like this I wouldn't have to manually compress the js files each time I change something.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that using [sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) (by default in Rails 3.1+) or [jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/)