# Exempt Js file from Minify in Rails Application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, minify, uglifier

I am using rails 4. I want to exempt 1 Js file from being minified. I am using uglifier gem (1.3.0)

adding Js file in script tag will minify the Js? can someone guide me about that?

looked into articles which are suggesting to add link to Js file in script tag

some other referenced articles I've looked into
[Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329537/rails-3-2-exclude-single-js-file-from-minification)

[Article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922692/selective-rails-3-2-asset-pipeline-compression-per-file)

[Article 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306025/ruby-on-rails-minify-or-compress-javascript-files)